# SQL Developer Can't locate Java on Mac OS

Tags: macos, java, macos-mojave, jdk, jre

I have downloaded Oracle SQL Developer and when I attempt to run it i get the following message:

[image]

These are the java settings on my computer:

1. java -version: java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
2. "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -version : java version "1.8.0_211"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
3. which java: /usr/bin/java
4. echo $JAVA_HOME: blank
5. On the Java control panel in System preferences, the JRE path is: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

How can I get SQL developer to recognise my Java installation?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-relnotes-191-5458711.html) of the latest SQL Developer (v19.1)

> Java versions 10 and higher are not yet supported and will not work
>
> Oracle SQL Developer 19.1 release requires Oracle Java 8 or 9, with a minimum version of 1.8 update 121. Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to download the latest version.
>
> *Source: Oracle*